# Which entries in the dos header are necessary?

Tags: dos, portable-executable

I am writing a PE generator, I need to know which entries in the DOS header section are necessary for execution on NT based systems.

I checked some exes on my drive and most entries in the DOS header are 0 but I am not sure if this is the norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On an NT system the loader just checks for the magic numbers at the beginning `MZ / 0x4d 0x5a` and then the member `e_lfanew` to get the NT header offset.